# Best practices when working with videos in flash?

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming

Are there any standard practices for Video encoding, streaming, etc?

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Answer (score 0):

**Adobe Media Encoder**
Start with Adobe Media Encoder, because it ensures the right codec. Right meaning, flv and fv4 files will import in to Flash easily. Other standards would depend on the scope of your project.

Here's a link to learn more
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AdobeMediaEncoder/4.0/WS053EA898-B158-4c20-8147-FE0881119BE2.html